# Creating customizable module in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I am new to Customization in Angular. I want to create a customizable module in Angular 6.

I would like to create it and include in Node_modules folder so that other teams can use it.

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dragdrop

This drag and drop functionality is the one I am trying to implement.

How can I get started? What are the best approaches and how can I achieve this?

Comment: This is not the right way, you can declare as a shared module, and use it

Comment: @Shohel Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Prime, I suggest that you should customize it by CSS only. If Prime's components don't fit with your problem, you should try to create it from scratch. It is more easier to sustain your components later.

Comment: I am trying to create from scratch. Can you please give me an example on how to jump start and how to deploy that into node_modules?